# Raspberry Pi doesn't recognize default password

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I have just received a RaspberryPi and installed the software on an SD card, but when the Raspberry Pi boots up and asks for the login, the default login and password information won't work.

Occasionally, the flashing software (balenaEtcher) fails to flash to the SD card, even though the SD is fully functional and not corrupted

**Stats:**

- **RaspberryPi Stats:** RaspberryPi 3, Model B
- **Software:** Raspbian (all versions)
- **Flashing Software:** balenaEtcher
- **SD card Stats:** SanDisk Industrial, 16 GB, micro SD

I have already tried re-instaling the software, formatted the SD, and installing other raspbian software (NOOBS is too big for the SD card).

They all end up with the same result.

After RaspberryPi 3 Boots up (The command line):

```
Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 raspberrypi tty1

raspberrypi login: pi
Password:
raspberry

Login incorrect
raspberrypi login: _
```

I expected the RaspberryPi to login and finish, but instead it ended up saying 'login incorrect'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to install NOOBS, and I should be able to because I have double the recommended space on my SD card ([RaspberryPi Documentation](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/raspberry-pi-setting-up)).

Also, I figured this out later, but when you type a password, it wont show. Pushing 'enter' then typing in the password really quick won't help.

Answer (score 0):

For me solved with: `sudo nano /etc/shadow`.
Change the rows for the users 'root' and 'pi' in this file:

```
root:$1$rberrypi$wq1QpnEwQrzk7LMgrodbg1:19480:0:99999:7:::
pi:$1$rberrypi$22iblaIkO7krJXw2Y837v0:19480:0:99999:7:::
```